# 6 week average - but one week before the start date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've been trying to create a measure that would give me the 6 week average of revenue but starting with one week/ 7 days before the start date (as I want to exclude the week before).

I can get the six week average but I cant get it to start a week before the start date.
.Rev6WeekAvg = CALCULATE([.Revenue],DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Day],LASTDATE ('Date'[Day]),-42,DAY)/6

Any suggestions please - I tried to create a variable but it wouldn't let me pass it as the start date for DATESINPERIOD

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You almost have it.  You just need to use DATEADD to shift your six week period back a few days.

```
.Rev6WeekAvg =
CALCULATE(
    [.Revenue]
    ,DATEADD(
        DATESINPERIOD(
            'Date'[Day]
            ,LASTDATE ('Date'[Day])
            ,-42,DAY)
        , -7
        , DAY
    )
)
/6
```